# How to get apostrophes correct in function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the " characters correct but I'm struggeling currently.
I have the bellow code.

```
var text ="";//This variable will be initialized later.
table
   .append(
      $('<tr>').append(
          $('<td>').html("Test:")
      )
      .append(
          $('<td>').append(
              $('<a>')
                  .attr("title", "Press to change the value").attr("href", "#")
                  .attr(
                      "onclick",
                      "AlertBox(\"Please use this dialog to update comment information.\",null,\"" + data.Id + "\",null);"
                  )
                  .text(data.Test)
          )
      )
   );
```

but instead of

```
"AlertBox(\"Please use this dialog to update comment information.\",null,\"" + data.Id + "\",null);")
```

I want the following

```
"AlertBox(\"Please use this dialog to update comment information.'," + text + "," + updateComment + "," +  data.Id +  "," + [data.Username,data.timestamp]
```

That is I want to call a function that takes the following parameters.

```
function AlertBox(question, text, successFunction, params,additionalCommentInfoParams){}
```

Problem is that I can't seem to get the commas correct. Can you perhaps give me a hint on how to print out the " characters in order for it to work, I have not done this in Jquery before. Also is there perhaps a nice tool that can generate this for me for future use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why arent you binding a click function instead of writing it in an onclick attribute?

Comment: like this? **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/wwLt447b/)** (removed variables but you can see how the `/` works with `"`.

Comment: How about adding the `additionalCommentInfoParams` to the `params`, sorry, had to say it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex mentioned in the comments, if you want an alert to pop up after an element is clicked, it will be easier to specify via the jQuery `click` function, like so:

```
var text ="";//This variable will be initialized later.
table.append($('<tr>')
    .append($('<td>')
    .html("Test:"))
    .append($('<td>')
    .append($('<a>')
    .attr("title", "Press to change the value")
    .attr("href", "#")
    .click(function(){
        AlertBox("Please use this dialog to update comment information.",null,"" + data.Id,null);
    })
    .text(data.Test))));
```

Comment: jQuery `.click`, not `.onclick` (or better yet: `.on('click',function(){});`). Other than that: exactly what i was going to suggest :-)